# Why does SQL Server force me to drop the table to be able to alter a field from DateTime to DateTime2(3)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, alter-table

I am trying to alter a table field - with some rows in it - from `DateTime` to `DateTime2(3)`.

But the SQL Server Management Studio complains that I have drop and re-create the table.

But why?

Isn't `DateTime2(3)` has more precision than `DateTime` type? It should be fine, should not it be?

Comment: Which *database system* are you using?

Comment: @Lion "*Management Studio*" implies SQL Server.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896713/sql-server-management-studio-adding-moving-columns-require-drop-and-re-create

Comment: Are you using the GUI tool to alter columns or a real ALTER TABLE statement? The GUI tools often incorrectly insist you drop and recreate tables when the pure SQL operation performs fine.

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431901/forcing-management-studio-to-use-alter-table-instead-of-drop-create

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a setting in SSMS that will allow you to do what you want.. Menu-Tools-Options-Designers-Prevent saving changes that require table re-creaction.

SSMS has a habit of recreating almost any changes you do. It should be just fine to only alter the column data type with something like this.

```
alter table TableName alter column ColName datetime2(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without rebuilding the table (as Management Studio does behind the scenes).

```
ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN D DateTime2(3) [NOT NULL]
```

This will be less resource intensive up front but leave the "old" column behind in the data pages so will have an effect ongoing until you rebuild the table.

Comment: didn't know that about alter table alter column.  Not saying you're wrong, but do you have a reference?  Thanks!

Comment: @BenThul [Here's one](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2006/10/13/alter-table-will-not-reclaim-space.aspx)